# YouTube Data API - Number of Results - Maven

Tags: maven, youtube-api

I am trying to get videos from youtube in two different ways

a) First using youtube-google-api client library following the guidelines and sample code from here https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java#search_by_keyword
Nevertheless, since I am implementing in a mavenized project Ihave difficulty in finding the dependency for  'com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.Auth" which is required for the following block of code:

```
try {

        youtube = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, new HttpRequestInitializer()    {
            public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
            }
        }).setApplicationName("youtube-cmdline-search-sample").build();
```

b)Second I simply send a GET request to YouTube like this:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=madonna&type=video&key={API_KEY}
but I am able to receive only 5 results, although I've read in several Stackoverflow related questions that I can receive up to 50 videos.This is not feasible even if I set the "max-results" parameter.

Could anyone help me to deal with these issues? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second way Write **maxResults=50** as a parameter instead of max-results=50.
Use YouTube Data Api v3 api explorer to understand parameters very well.

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/youtube/v3/

```
    https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=madonna&maxResults=50&type=video&key={API_KEY}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and the link you provided.